# How to select * from 'x' in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I'm trying to receive all fields in my database in my API call

My code:

```
exports.objfields = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    var db = mongo.connection;  
    var objeto = req.headers.objeto;
    const result = db.db.collection(objeto).find();
    return res.status(200).send({message:result});
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

For results 200 it's returning me the following sentence  `"message": {"_events": {},"_eventsCount": 0}` , how can I return the fields in the API call? (obs. I also tried `find({})`, but it returns the same thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two issues with your code:

1. Are you sure it should be: `db.db.collection` and not `db.collection` ? Hard to tell without seeing your DB init code, but just double check that first.
2. You need to use async/await to wait for MongoDB to return the result to your Node application:

```
const result = await db.collection(objeto).find();
```

`find()` returns a JS Promise, not a direct value immediately. For more details on async/await, you can check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

If you end up with a Cursor object but cannot see the values, try to convert the Cursor into an array using `toArray()`:

For example:

```
const cursor = collection.find({});
const allValues = await cursor.toArray();
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#return-an-array-of-all-documents